# How do I change values of objects in a JFrame from another class?

Tags: java, swing

I need to change values of JLabel and the background color of the frame in my options JFrame.

I am programming a game and I have an options screen. The screen is obviously in another class, but I have things like the game's main frame's background and text in a JLabel. I try import the frame class and use things like `Frame().getContentPane().setBackground()`, but it does not work for some reason. Could someone please help me. Also, my frame class(the main one) has `public class Frame extends JFrame`. I do not want to rewrite my code, but if it is necessary, I will do it. This kind of post might have already been made, but I might have phrased it differently.

Comment: You really want to understand the [model view controller](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+model+view+controller&rlz=1C5GCEM_enAU1020AU1020&oq=java+model+view+controller&aqs=chrome..69i57.3000j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) concept and [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) as a basic principle

Comment: You should post a [mcve] that demonstrates *one* of these problems, then ask about that problem.  It sounds like you have several issues and it's best to tackle them one at a time.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: better not name a custom class the same a framework class - sooner or later code readers will be confused (including yourself :)

Answer (score -2):

You create a static void in the Frame class, then declare the method in the other class, as the info about the game's background and such is in the frame class. CODE: in Frame class:

```
     public static void changeColor{
     JColorChooser color = new JColorChooser;
     JColorChooser.showInputDialog(null, "Choose a background!");
     Frame.getContentPane().setBackground(color);
}
```

in Options screen class:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
     if(e.getSource()==backgroundColorChooser){
          Frame.changeBackGroundColor();
}
}
```

Comment: don't use static scope .. instead organize communication between your views, ideally by a model (as already suggested by @James_D in a comment to your question)